# Lightweight, commercially available robotic arms

Tags: mobile-robot, robotic-arm

I was wondering what options are there in terms of lightweight (< 5 lbs) robotic arms. I see [Robai Cyton Gamma 300](http://www.robai.com/products.php?prdt_id=1), and [CrustCrawler AX18](http://www.crustcrawler.com/products/AX-18F%20Smart%20Robotic%20Arm/) look like interesting options. What lightweight arms do people use/like?

Comment: In general, survey questions are not a good fit, and will get closed or downvoted. This site is for _specific_ problems you are having. If you want to pursue this question, could you please add more details? For instance, what is your intended application, what does "interesting" mean, what are the cost constraints / programability constraints? Think of someone who may visit this page in the future. How would they know if they can use this information for _their_ application?

Comment: @Josh though i'm not answering, appreciate your comment. Because many of the others just down-vote/close-vote without saying any reason (I feel like it's so rude).  And JES what josh said is right. Refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) to know more.

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* JES, but we try to avoid [shopping questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) as they are not very useful to future visitors to the site and go out of date quickly. We prefer [practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask) so if you can rephrase your question to ask what things you need to consider when selecting a robot arm, you may get answers which are both useful now and in the future. Thanks,

Comment: Welcome to robotics.SE. A few more details would be helpful. How much weight should it be able to lift, do you need a certain number of degrees of freedom, do you need it to connect directly to a PC or are you comfortable with it connecting to something like an Arduino?

Comment: Sorry about that (I'm new to robotics.SE). I want to lift approximately 500 grams. Initially, looking for 4 DoF+. I would be comfortable programming Arduino.

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought about cardboard? http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/392540503/cardboard-robot-robotic-arm-and-smart-phone-camera

Answer (score 0):

The [OWI robotic arm](http://www.owirobots.com/cart/html/owi-535-robotic-arm-edge-kit.html) is a cheap starting possibility for $30. 
There is an [instructables tutorial](http://www.instructables.com/id/Intro-and-what-youll-need/) on how to connect it to arduino.